# How can run sudo commands inside another user, or grant a user the same privileges as an admin?

Tags: users, postgresql

Noob here, so just please tell me if this is stupid. Apologies also if the jargon in the title is a little off.

Here's my problem. I have a user, `postgres` which I use for all tasks involving the postgres database server. However, I'm constantly running into `Permission denied` when running scripts in postgres. I have to keep logging out of postgres, chowning certain directories to postgres, and, obviously maybe, you can't run `sudo` when inside `postgres`. If I do Ubuntu gives me this message:

```
postgres is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Kinky. How can I run sudo inside postgres or give postgres more privileges?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you must add the postgres user to the sudo group by running the below command.

```
sudo usermod -a -G sudo postgres
```

Logout and login back to take effect.

If the above command won't work then you need to drop into root shell and then apply the above command..

How to drop into root shell?

- Restart your PC.
- On the group menu, select Ubuntu Recovery Option.
- select `root`
- From the root shell, run the above mentioned command.

Comment: Ah awesome. There's no security issues with doing this? I'll be able to run sudo commands inside postgres?

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer ,please tick my answer as correct.

Comment: I tried it but it did not work for me.

Comment: @AshutoshNigam drop into root shell and run the above command.